# How to filter a record using the sub-record, using criteria on the netsuite saved search?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, netsuite

I'm trying to filter a record using the document number only when one of the items is with 0 amount... this has many application throughout NetSuite. Unfortunately, if you try to use simple case when {amount}=0 it will filter only the item but not the document.

Does anyone have any suggestions or encounter this before?

[record image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D290T.png)

Comment: Just trying to clarify, you have a transaction search where you are trying to include all transactions where one of the line items has a `0` amount, or you are trying to exclude transactions where any of the lines has a `0` amount?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filter a search by one of the line items. Enter 'Item Fields' into the search criteria field (its at the bottom of the list) and select from the popup list.

Just be aware if you chose any of the item fields for the 'results' tab it will return data for ALL items in each document in the result, even those that do not match the original criteria. A workaround for this is to set all the criteria fields to 'Item Fields' if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with with a Summary Type Criteria. In the Results subtab, make sure to GROUP your results by the Transaction Number, and in the Criteria subtab, click Summary, and add -

```
Summary Type = Minimum
Field = Amount
Description is 0.00
```